# How do non-instantiated loaded Prefabs compare to instantiated ones?

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor, unity-game-engine

## Example

In Unity5, assuming that a GameObject with name "SomeObject" was stored as a prefab at `Assets/Resources/SomeObject.prefab`, I know that I can create an instance of the prefab as follows:

```c#
GameObject prefab   = Resources.Load<GameObject>("SomeObject");
GameObject instance = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
```

Once executed, the `instance` GameObject will be a copy of the original "SomeObject" prefab, and will have been placed in the current active scene with the name "SomeObject(Clone)".

---

As far as I understand, the `GameObject prefab` represents the actual prefab asset, and any changes made to it (setting name, adding components, etc) are written to the original prefab asset, and these changes persist even after exiting editor play mode.

## Questions

1. Since all GameObjects are normally stored in a scene, and the `scene` property on `GameObject prefab` in the above example seems to be Unloaded/Invalid/Unnamed, where exactly should I consider this special GameObject to be? I seem to be able to do everything with it that I can do with normal GameObjects, short of being visible in the hierarchy/scene view.

   Is it effectively in some kind of limbo state, or a special PseudoScene? It seems to persist through `LoadSceneMode.Single` scene changes, but is not like the special `DontDestroyOnLoad` scene that Objects are moved to when passed into `GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(...)`.
2. Are there any other noteworthy differences between `prefab` and `instance` in the above example, other than lifetime changes, the invalid scene and being different objects from one another (Having different `GetInstanceID()`, etc)?
3. Since calling `GameObject.Instantiate(...)` on `prefab`yields a GameObject that *is* in a valid scene, is there any way to manually create GameObjects that are in a similar 'no scene' state? I am aware that Unity intends for all GameObjects to be in scenes and so this is purely an academic question.

I have tried looking through the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) of the [functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) [involved](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), but none go into the technical details of what specifically is happening when you call `Resources.Load` on a prefab resource.

Comment: As you can probably tell by me effectively shoving 3 questions in at once, I'm at a point where I lack the intuition to really know what it is that I don't know, if that makes sense. To try again: Since Resources.Load yields a GameObject in a state that can't be manually created, I am curious about the exact nature of these differences, and was hoping someone with more knowledge of what's going on behind the scenes could provide insight into the systems in play here that may not be immediately obvious from the normal documentation. My apologies for not being able to word this any clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Where exactly should I consider this special GameObject to be?

It's in a separate file and not referenced in the scene. Once `Resources.Load<GameObject>("SomeObject");` is called, it is loaded into the **memory** waiting to be used when `GameObject.Instantiate` is called.

If it is declared as `public GameObject prefab;` and assigned from the Editor  instead of `GameObject prefab Resources.Load<GameObject>("SomeObject");`, it will be loaded into the memory automatically when the scene loads.

> 2.Are there any other noteworthy differences between prefab and object?

Yes.

Prefabs cannot be destroyed with the `Destroy` or `DestroyObject` function. It has to be destroyed with the `DestroyImmediate` function by passing `true` to its second arguement: `DestroyImmediate(prefab, true);`

> 3.Is there any way to manually create GameObjects that are in a similar 'no scene' state?

No, there is no way to manually create GameObjects that are in a similar 'no scene' state.

*Although you can fake it.*

The closest thing to that is to make the GameObject invisible in the Editor's *Hierarchy* and *Inspector* tabs by modifying the GameObjects's [`hideFlags`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-hideFlags.html) variable then deactivate that GameObject.

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("SomeObject");
obj.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy | HideFlags.HideInInspector;
```

After that, deactivate the GameObject:

```
obj.SetActive(false);
```

Now, the GameObject is invisible in the Editor and it is also invisible in the Scene and Game View.

---

There is really no big difference between prefabs and a typical GameObject. Prefab is just a container that holds the GameObject so that it can be re-used and shared between scenes. Modifying one prefab will update any instance of it.

Imagine when you have hundreds of GameObjects of the-same type in the scene and need to modify all of them. With prefab, you only need to modify one of them or just the prefab then click *Apply* to update other instances. This is the only thing you should think of prefabs.

Comment: I was also curious how the link between the prefab gameObject and the original prefab is established, and how it is serialized immediately. Poking at https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled it seems that `Resources.Load` ultimately leads to an extern function, so it's somewhere inside the C++ side of Unity. A friend pointed out that a prefab is probably a specialized C++ object that's living with a GameObject .net interface. Any thoughts?

Comment: I had to look at this via `.Net reflector` to verify. It is calling a native C++  function that takes path of the prefab and the prefab type of the prefab: `public static extern Object Load(string path, Type systemTypeInstance);`. I think that the C++ side will load the file with the provided path then de-serialize the data inside that prefab file into memory then return it as `Object`. The prefab file format is proprietary so it's hard to guess what's inside of it unless you work for Unity and have the C++ source code.

Comment: Just for anyone else that learns about `hideFlags` here for the first time, it may be worth also appending `HideFlags.HideFlags.DontSave` or just using `HideFlags.HideAndDontSave` instead, since having objects you can't see pile up could be a potential problem.